# Problem in getting url of custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, geturl

I am new to magento,I have created a custom module for magento backend. I don't know how to get its url, I have tried some help from online, nothing happens, please tell what should I pass into getUrl function.How should I use 
$url = Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('/your_module/index');
my file

confic.xml

```
<modules>
    <Petra_DailyOrders>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Petra_DailyOrders>
</modules>

<global>
    <helpers>
        <petra_dailyorders>
            <!-- Helper definition needed by Magento -->
            <class>Mage_Core_Helper</class>
        </petra_dailyorders>
    </helpers>
</global>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <petra_dailyorders before="Mage_Adminhtml">Petra_DailyOrders_Adminhtml</petra_dailyorders>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>

<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <petra>
                <file>dailyorders.xml</file>
            </petra>
        </updates>   
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

Comment: I tried answer given on this and other forums, I am unable to solve it, so now I came here for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

generate it like this:

```
$url = Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('admintml/your_module/index');
```

So you should place your controller in

`Petra/DailyOrders/controllers/Adminhtml/ControllerName.php` and call it like this

```
$url = Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('admintml/controllername/index');
```

Comment: my controller is   class Petra_DailyOrders_Adminhtml_CustomController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {....} and I tried as you said "$url = Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('admintml/customController/index');" it is not giving url,  it is giving "http://marketing.com/index.php/admintml/customController/index/" and original url is "http://marketing.com/index.php/admin/custom/"

Comment: That is not a correct url

Comment: try with `$url = Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('admintml/custom/index');`

Comment: already tried, it gives "http://marketing.com/index.php/admintml/custom/index/"  method is just appending the argument in front of "marketing.com/index.php"